# Conditionally change the direction of a "for loop"?

Tags: actionscript-3, conditional-statements

Is it possible to conditionally change the direction of a for loop in ActionScript?

**Example:**

```
for(if(condition){var x = 0; x<number; x++}else{var x=number; x>0; x--}){
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Interesting requirement.  One way to keep the for is:

```
var start, loop_cond, inc; 
if(condition) 
{ 
    start = 0; 
    inc = 1; 
    loop_cond = function(){return x < number}; 
} 
else 
{ 
    start = number - 1; 
    inc = -1; 
    loop_cond = function(){return x >= 0}; 
} 
for(var x = start; loop_cond(); x += inc) 
{ 
    // do something
}
```

We setup the start value, a function for the termination condition, and either a positive or negative increment.  Then, we just call the function and use `+=` to the do the increment or decrement.

Answer (score 6):

ActionScript has the ternary operator, so you could do something like:

```
for (var x = cond ? 0 : number; cond ? x < number : x > 0; cond ? x++ : x--) {
}
```

But this is pretty ugly.  :-)

You might also need/want to put some parens around pieces of that.  I'm not sure about the operator precedence.

You might also consider using a higher order function.  Imagine you have:

```
function forward (count, func) {
    for (var x = 0; x < count; x++) {
        func(x);
    }
}

function backward (count, func) {
    for (var x = count - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
        func(x);
    }
}
```

Then you could do:

```
(condition ? forward : backward) (number, function (x) {
     // Your loop code goes here
})
```

Comment: I was about to post that as my third and worst option for him. I'm going to upvote you but only because you said it was ugly `:-)` *This is not a good solution, don't use it Moshe!*

Comment: OK. And your new, edited answer is *slick*. I approve and wish I could upvote again now :-)

Comment: mang? (ps, nice answer, not correct because I didn't use it, but +1)

Comment: @Moshe since my last name starts with a "G" I think that was "Thanks, man G!" ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a `while` loop instead:

```
var continueLooping, x;

if(condition)
{
  x = 0
  continueLooping = (x < number);
}
else
{
  x = number;
  continueLooping = (x > 0);
}

while (continueLooping)
{
  // do something
  if(condition)
  {
    x++;
    continueLooping = (x < number);
  }
  else
  {
    x--;
    continueLooping = (x > 0);
  }
}
```

If you really want a for loop, you should use two of them:

```
function doSomething()
{
  //doSomething
}

if(condition)
{
  for(var x = 0; x<number; x++)
  {
    doSomething(x);
  }
}
else
{
  for(var x=number; x>0; x--})
  {
    doSomething(x);
  }
}
```